# Unknow Chinese Program in my PC (Windows Embedded 8)

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer

I am seeing an unknown program in my list of softwares through which I can play video stuff.

I have also checked Control Panel, and there is no such program installed in my PC. As I don't understand the language, kindly help me how to get rid of this program.

It has also disturbed my video settings for running different kind of media files.

[image]

Comment: I am going to guess the applications is a Windows Store application.

Comment: @Ramhound, I don't think so. As I haven't installed any Windows Store application or I haven't used store for the past month I guess.

Comment: Feel free to check.  If it isn't located in the list of installed applications, then the only explanation, is that it isn't a Win32 application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I have an unknown Chinese program on my PC

[image]

A Google [Reverse Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivbHnIW2d87QfSGZxQ6Di1MPpe7GPXJXj2h6QNq6d8rLAfZRmZjPyBXvSVVZ-QVt6LrVh3wRxzx02WWVKcYCkY12gS9me9WjC-b9YFpjrL1FpiNjxOGSlZl3idlb8TI2F5b0v26olVpCFf8uJ4MFwWgbrrYgZ6dd66aT9Eqyc8glX0BFuK1Khu8c28t_1MWM7ai8cRVLEs17sOGd4ZSLPDbhbzqcoJ6V7fhsMxnQVhx3asAsxEt2N9X_1YE5IzqAryWbvjO71-ElqzGpQ-ATrnx_1ZCO_1aY6DUh1vCTyn5agtXeVa7Oi9YjZ7C3Do1Jg7nvvDD3qXxqr8YFmp26VSA1QBEQxb0NhGV4rb8weAZy51B_1aTX3LaiKvi5_1y5B5xd95iML1noEgBXxvHi0uuxKgDOrLozrs83Y7cqAMAH_1OL7hCmQlGoF6FdwNSYQ6N_1fpEB1U8lKhrNK-cPLnXP4nWmQM3tGl95BWtWk6DKoAvFk-jvZDg_159t4VPWe4ui-6_1tSPqQ2pQ2xAPHVunTQ8iAFGpmodumLH6efob1oTkOKBvJNGO-Cl4BHIB5aO8eUFs4En56WSZFKDCqp1sIyofA9d8TY0Ldkjx2jZ-G2-gngflFOGcW-PTvsYpANVvTfIiEPi1Ud-s_10ANcuyLUoQCo3kimAO9FqHtP_1tRxrvELKwmQF9KlHdzDcNh7T0VIJnJ4flYU9BHpoVEB8eRzCNkaQ0vaPTnJ4ycR1C-CRm4zgO_1jfrQ5sLxWM0p7FlshtWsuhjb6hoVuqpf_1IWMbIu6xnvLknz81L0V8sK8QxMtQjoJKy_1hlZr8l77G4j1TkEUytA292uG02yP2qcemBAtTiolC1K0sU7Z1S9-cpGnFalGayDPpZJHcsQ9YyQRm7Yc1Zr5yfsOhNsyQmZwblhiJbX-fi0MAC7JN5gRvwl8kZhVhOxchjpoy6ve08COM1lzHeaT-dMKcS0N-Ffmq52uJ9K6e7PsBsQfdjOh2KYnDGyVgRCUwsXj1omN0z2g9vAp4-RZxQnJvKROrkqyhGmGiwP_1Wk3MIwnR2lVFOxG4xOxyxBIxFyi3YA7b0uBHBYb4eetFFAb5WccSISTZP1-ntwxgQPKBVvrsIW6Y34RcBKj6F7oPl-DG2bW0MIl5MJ3qIodpOQKRyhOQcYSXivlFa1L_1WEj_1dcATlnsqBdIG7ZD5fzsqIXY7LnmILYDUwy7hEFEghViJkli_18hH-aRzbe3HyjHdAM4TMoBvcNOeAbZanaQrQQecaX3s9pyic5v22hXtKITPzJoBMqoRD-CFz0V6vGISFK7gRyuD9a0P3YwuAh35XQjsEG05wBDm_11VyrY3gO6V09xNVofMsl07R9cenfmDz59GM4eKZs9DdSm2w33KV9GLRHz9qSIUqMpjYs8iyODIxJ1g-N9rxqRoWg212x0ONHDWEezl6PE6J_1v2xgy7guG44MnmwOxDpLJdR20161vhs-6xUHicDMpG-9haEf3hhL_1i0pzhBPwtyu-lmBPeGN3CUg&hl=en) using the [icon](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/5BGJpbQVcNp7Y4tmFWQmUR_Ognu7INMlZDoCU3e645VblNTo_fiwuuAwwUYnVV5B6TM_=s42) from your image can be used to identify the program.

It is `GeePlayer.exe`.

It is apparently a Trojan (W32.HfsAdware.A55D, dangerous, high risk)

Please see [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit) for removal instructions.

---

> ```
> Antivirus Report of GEEPLAYER.EXE:
> GEEPLAYER.EXE     W32.HfsAdware.A55D
> GEEPLAYER.EXE Dangerous
> GEEPLAYER.EXE High Risk
> ```
>
> We suggest you to remove GEEPLAYER.EXE from your computer as soon as
>   possible.
>
> ```
> GEEPLAYER.EXE is known as: W32.HfsAdware.A55D
> MD5 of GEEPLAYER.EXE = ba043cd6c2aa1d793fe901fd6510ea25
> GEEPLAYER.EXE size is 609896 bytes.
> Full path on a computer: %PROGRAM FILES%\IQIYI VIDEO\LSTYLE\GEEPLAYER.EXE
> Related Files:
> %Program Files%\IQIYI Video\LStyle\GBase.dll
> %Program Files%\IQIYI Video\LStyle\GdiPlus.dll
> %Program Files%\IQIYI Video\LStyle\GeePlayer.exe
> %Program Files%\IQIYI Video\LStyle\GetHardwareInfo.dll
> %Program Files%\IQIYI Video\LStyle\libcurl.dll
> ```

Source [GEEPLAYER.EXE Malware Removal Guide](http://www.greatis.com/appdata/d/g/geeplayer.exe.htm)